# Refactoring form fields and Stimulus JS so to not repeat :data-action once for each form field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, submit, stimulusjs

I've the following form

```
<%= 
  form_for(
    model,
    html: {
      :'data-controller' => 'enable-submit-button-if-fields-changed'
    }
  ) do |form|
%>
  <%= form.text_field(:title, :'data-action' => 'input->enable-submit-button-if-fields-changed#enableSubmit') %>
  <%= form.text_area(:description, :'data-action' => 'input->enable-submit-button-if-fields-changed#enableSubmit') %>
  <%= form.file_field(:picture, :'data-action' => 'input->enable-submit-button-if-fields-changed#enableSubmit') %>
  <%= form.check_box(:delete_image, :'data-action' => 'input->enable-submit-button-if-fields-changed#enableSubmit') %>
  <%#= other input fields... %>
<% end %>
```

and the following Stimulus JS controller

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="enable-submit-button-if-fields-changed"
export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.element.querySelector('input[type=submit]').disabled = true;
  }

  enableSubmit() {
    this.element.querySelector('input[type=submit]').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

They are mean to enable the submit button when an input field changes.

As you can see in the form, I've added the `:'data-action' => 'input->enable-submit-button-if-fields-changed#enableSubmit'` once for each input field.

What is the way to refactor that so to not repeat `:'data-action'` once for each field e.g. just stating the `:'data-controller' => 'enable-submit-button-if-fields-changed'` on the form and make (through Stimulus) all its inner input fields to JS-enable the submit button on change? Or, should I continue repeat `:'data-action'` once for each field?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add one event listener to the `form`, as the `input` event will bubble.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event